# Confusion with `if` `else` and `while`

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, if-statement

I have a code where it should check if the result equals to `8` it need to show something and if not it need to show something `else` and all of that happens inside of a `while` loop.

```
while ($row_fpages2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_fanpage2))
{
    if ( $row_fpages2['client'] != NULL ) {

        //GRAPHS
    $sql = "SELECT likes, date FROM statistics_pages WHERE idnum = '".$idnum."' AND page_name = '".$row_fpages2['page_name']."' ORDER BY `statistics_pages`.`date` DESC LIMIT 8";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result2) {
        $data   = array();

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            $data[]   = $row["likes"];
        }

    if ($result2 == 8) {
    $c_data = count($data)-1;
    $final = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c_data; $i++) {
    $final[] = getZeroResult($data[$i], $data[$i+1]);
}
    $data_string = join(",", $final);

    $stats = '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=240x140&cht=ls&chd=t:0,0|'.$data_string.'&chg=20,20&chls=0.75,-1,-1|6,4,1&chm=o,FF9900,1,-1,7,-1|b,3399CC44,0,1,0"></img>';

    } else {
        $stats = '<img src="images/stats_un.jpg"></img>';
    };



    } else {
        print('MySQL query failed with error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

echo '...';
```

The problem is that the first output always showing the `( == 8)` (even if it is not equals to 8) instead of the `else` output.

Then if i have 2 or more everything comes above the first one is correct but the first one is still showing the `( == 8)`.

Any help?

Comment: It might help to properly indent everything so you can see the blocks clearly.

Comment: what exactly must be equal to 8 .. the number of rows ???
Because I dont think you can do this 
 if ($result2 == 8) 

$result2 holds a resource id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do the following which is incorrect:

```
$result2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
...
if ($result2 == 8) {
```

The return value of `mysql_query` is a resource not an int. What is that you are trying to do there ?

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot with that little tip. I just written `$row_r2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);` and then replaced the `mysql_query` with the fetched arrays var. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you would like to use

```
if(strlen($result2) == 8){
               ...
         }
```

instead of

```
if($result2 == 8){
               ...
         }
```

Hope that solves your problem.